# How do I calculate single proportion in R using metaprop?

Tags: r

I am conducting a meta-analysis on secondary attack rate within multigenerational households. I am attempting to use a random-effects model on my data (as below) and subsequently plot a forest plot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byw2r.png)

I have thus far used the meta package in R, using metaprop function for the calculation of a single proportion. however, the issue lies in that some of my studies were smaller and as such, the secondary attack rate is 100%, giving me a standard error of 0. with my data, R says that my n must be positive.
this is my code:
forest_plot <- metaprop (SAR, SE, data = data1, sm = PRAW, incr = 0.5, addincr = TRUE, comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, hakn = FALSE, method.tau = DL)

How do I fix this? thank you!

Comment: I encourage you to read the metaprop function documentation before asking for this question: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/meta/versions/4.9-6/topics/metaprop Indeed, you are putting `SAR` in the `event` argument which requires a number

Comment: yes, SAR is my event and my SE is my n. I'm quite new to this and im not sure if this is right but i have also tried swapped the two and R did not accept that either, claiming that observations cannot be larger than my event.

Comment: the way i understand it, the issue is that my SE is 0 (due to the fact that my SAR is 100%, for example in a small household of 5 where all were infected). i tried to fix this using incr command but it doesnt seem to work. is there something im missing?

Comment: metaprop is calculating overall proportion from studies reporting of single proportion, events is the number of event, n is the number of observations. In your dataset you are showing us a proportion in percentage format as well as a standard error. I believe you have to reformat your dataset, if I take your exemple of SAR=100% with 5 infected, I think events = 5 and obs = 5 and you have to modify this for each of your dataset row

Comment: i reformatted my data as you suggested and that worked. thank you for your help in clearing my confusion!